# Does it converge and find possibly the limit of: $\frac{n^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus

There is probably a much more "elegant solution than mine:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 27 \cdot 256... }{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 24...} \le n \cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{3}... $$  and it converges to infinity.

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the $\frac{n^n}{n!}$ terms together for $n=1,2,\ldots$??

Comment: Note that $n!\leq n^{n-1}$.

Comment: A common strategy for this problem is to show that it is monotonic increasing and unbounded.

Comment: Elegance here might be a subject of debate. To a working mathematician, perhaps the most natural approach would be [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which tells us the rough size of $n!$ is like $\sqrt{n} n^n e^{-n}$, and so your ratio grows at the speed $e^n / \sqrt{n}$. But whether this is elegant depends on if you know about (and like) Stirling.

Comment: Please proofread this carefully. The numerical fraction is just nonsense. Moreover, does a quantity which is *less* than a quantity approaching infinity necessarily approach infinity?

Comment: @prets You don't need anything like Stirling's formula for this elementary result. Trivially, $n!\leq n^{n-1}$, and so $\frac{n^n}{n!}\geq n$. Thus, the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: @Mark Perfectly true---I'm not saying Stirling is required, just attempting to comment on elegance. As in, when someone asks me to think about $n!$ for large $n$, what I imagine in my head is approximately $\sqrt{n} n^n / e^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply D'Alembert criterion with $a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}$:

$\lim\limits_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim\limits_n \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}=\lim\limits_n \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim\limits_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$.

Because this limit is $>1$, then $a_n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to note that $n!=\prod\limits_{k=2}^n k\leq n^{n-1}$. Thus:

$\frac{n^n}{n!}\geq n$

And so the limit is infinity.

Answer (score -1):

U can use the ratio test. We have to show, that a_k+1/a_k > 1. So, ((n+1)^(n+1)/(n+1)!)/(n^n/n!). A little bit of algebra and u will see, that this expression is greater than 1. It means that our sum is divergent to infinity.

Comment: Martin Vacas Vignolo wrote the same but more clearly